# How to break a list of numbers into parallel blocks

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've 480 numbers all in the one column of an Excel file. In the same file I want to divide these numbers into 60 columns each of 8 numbers:

.. sequence... `column 1`-->1-8, `column 2` --> 9-16, `column 3` -->17-24 ... etc.

For now, I've used copy/paste  but it takes a lot of time and doesn't seem to be an optimum solution.

Is there any short cut to get this done quickly?

Comment: Excel is probably not the right tool for the job that you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming data is in ColumnA of Sheet1 starting in Row1, I'd suggest copy first 8 into `A1:A8` then in `B1` enter:

> =INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&(COLUMN()-1)*8+ROW())

copy across and down as required, then copy whole spreadsheet and Paste Special Values.